# A condition on a function to be group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G_1,G_2$ be two groups and $f:G_1\longrightarrow G_2$ be a function which satisfies the condition $$f(a^2ba^{-1})=f(a^2)f(b)f(a)^{-1}, \forall\, a,b\in G_1.$$Is it true that $f$ is a group homomorphism?

Comment: What do you think about it? Any thoughts, ideas...

Comment: There is in fact a counterexample over $\mathbb{Z}$ (under addition).

Comment: There is, in fact, a counterexample over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.